# Teoria do Garden Path (Teoria do Labirinto)

Tags: gramática, ambiguidades

Eu estava lendo [esta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden-path_sentence) pagina da wikipedia. E nela é apresentada a seguinte frase em inglês

> "The old man the boat".

Inicialmente a frase acima parece não apresentar sentido algum. Mas uma análise (e um pouco de boa vontade) nos mostra que na realidade a frase teria como tradução algo próximo de "Os velhos operam o navio".

A confusão inicial é causada porque geralmente empregamos "old" ao papel de adjetivo e "man" ao de substantantivo. Nesse caso "man" é visto como [verbo](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/pt/dicionario/learner-english/man_2) e "old" como [substantivo](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/old), vale também ressaltar que "old" está no plural, pois deve concordar com o verbo.

Esses fatores geram uma frase extremamente peculiar e interessante.

Alguém conheceria algum exemplo em português desse tipo de contrução, *i.e.* uma frase gramaticalmente correta que começa de tal maneira que a interpretação mais provável de um leitor estará incorreta.

Eu acho que talvez seja um pouco difícil de construir um exemplo em português porque a gente conjuga demais os verbos e geralmente não podemos omitir conectivos tais como "que". Além de que, em português, o adjetivo vem depois do substantivo.

Caso exista algum exemplo creio que bons candidatos seriam frases que apresentem alguma das seguintes palavras: "apagou", "reza", "ensino", "entrada" e "embora". Pois essas palavras estão em classes gramaticais diferentes dependendo do contexto da frase.

Comment: Sua pergunta é "off topic" porque não tem uma resposta correta, mas dezenas de respostas que podem agradar ou não.  Também *"que apresentem alguma das seguintes palavras"* dá a impressão de ser um "puzzle"

Comment: Concordo que que é off-topic. Foi mais uma curiosidade minha do que qualquer outra coisa. Um assunto que me chamou a anteção. Não quis dar a entender que era um puzzle, pesso ate desculpas. Apenas quis tentar dar algumas ideias uma possível construção de tal frase. Posso excluir a questão se for o caso.

Comment: Nao concordo muito que "não tem uma resposta correta", ao meu ver é claro se a frase ira se encaixar ou não nos requisitos pedidos. Inclusive a pagina da wikipedia tem uma definição para o termo.

Comment: Quando eu digo que não hé resposta correta, é porque existem muitas respostas e você não pode marcar todas como corretas. Teria que escolher uma e iria escolhler a que mais lhe agradasse.  E então a resposta escolhida como correta seria baseada na sua opinião.

Comment: @Centaurus neste caso acho que o critério de desempate é claro. É aquele que postou a resposta primeira e ela atende as condições definidas pela wikipedia. Assim como quando duas pessoas postam resposta corretas a mesma pergunta dos fóruns do Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Centaurus esse post do PSE https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1002/what-are-some-friendly-casual-forms-of-address-in-brazilian-portuguese/1009#1009 , ao meu ver ele expressa tudo aquilo que vc é contra. Existem várias resposta e o autor escolhe a que ele gosta mais. A parte mais interesante disso tudo é que você foi a pessoa que respondeu a questão e ganhou mais upvotes. Não consigo ver porque a questão do link atende os padrões e a minha não. É exatamente a mesma construção. Eu encontrei uma situação em inglês e gostaria de ver se ela também ocorre em português.

Comment: @MatheusManzatto quanto a teorias não sei, mas deixei a minha resposta com link a um video que usa integralmente essa estrutura de frase.

Comment: @Centaurus vê o video da minha resposta que a escrita é genial. Especialmente lá para o fim, só um falante de Português poderia entender tal coisa :)

Comment: @MatheusManzatto  Não, a pergunta que eu respondi é sobre língua portuguesa.  A sua é tipo um puzzle.  É semelhante a pedir para citar palíndromes, palavras oxítonas que têm o maior número de sílabas, palavras que começam e terminam com a mesma letra, etc.   São tipos de pergunta bem differentes da que eu respondi.   Quanto a resposta, não se escolhe quem primeiro respondeu.  Dá-se algum tempo para que várias respostas sejam apresentadas e escolhe-se a melhor.  No caso da sua pergunta, várias respostas estariam corretas,  A escolha seria uma questão de opinião da sua parte.

Comment: *"o critério de desempate é claro. É aquele que postou a resposta primeira e ela atende as condições definidas pela wikipedia."*   Discordo totalmente.  Nós não estamos aqui para atender a condições definidas pela wikipedia.

Comment: Não acho que o tema da pergunta seja _off-topic_. Mas acho que a pergunta é _too-broad_, e que o seu formato não se adequa. O tema é _on-topic_, o conteúdo talvez não. (E sim, acho que a pergunta "linkada" é de formato _too broad_ também.)

Comment: Acho também que esta pergunta é difícil de ler, e podia ser muito melhorada... mas ["isso são outros 500"](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4958/qual-a-origem-e-significado-do-termo-outros-500-quinhentos). :)

Comment: Votei para fechar a pergunta, porque ela é "[chatty, open-ended](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)" - permite um conjunto possivelmente infinito de respostas diferentes e igualmente válidas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exemplo da [Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teoria_do_Garden_Path):

> O navio português entrava na baía o navio português.

Isto é: um navio impede/atrapalha/atravanca, na baía, o outro navio.

Comment: Essa frase é muito boa. Porque ela está correta? Nao consigo processar muito bem

Comment: @MatheusManzatto  *O navio português impede/atrapalha/atravanca na baía o navio português*. Uma variante talvez melhor é a seguinte: *O navio português entrava na baía o navio inglês*. Ou, talvez, *Um navio português entrava na baía um navio português.*

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se é exatamente o que está procurando, mas tenho uma frase que leva a pessoa a achar que ela (a frase) está incorreta.
A frase abaixo estará certa, ou errada?

> Foi fácil para mim fazer aquele negócio!

A frase quebra a regra: "Mim não faz nada", portanto pode levar a pessoa a julgar que a frase está errada, mas na verdade a frase está correta.

Fazendo a análise sintática, que admito possa não estar 100% correta:

> 1. (Foi (fácil (para (mim)))) (fazer (aquele (negócio)))!
> 2. (Foi (fácil (para (mim)))) = Oração subordinada substantiva predicativa = predicado
> 3. (fazer (aquele (negócio))! = Oração principal = sujeito

Colocando a frase na ordem direta, sujeito verbo predicado:

> Fazer aquele negócio foi fácil para mim.

A frase:

> Fazer aquele negócio foi fácil para eu!

Estaria incorreta, porque depois de preposição (para) usa-se o pronome oblíquo (mim).

Qual a explicação?

O "para mim" é complemento de *fácil*, e não sujeito de *fazer*; caso fosse sujeito de *fazer*, o correto seria "eu fazer".

Comment: Tenta dar um bocado de formatação aos teus textos para não serem uma sucessão de frases separadas. (Para o leitor é muito desagradável). Isso é mau vício que se apanha a escrever na internet. Tenta escrever parágrafos e usar listas para formatar o texto.

Comment: Claro que faltou uma edição final, mas isso não é um livro de poesia, é um forum da internet. Acredito que a diretriz "breve, sucinto e conciso" seja preferível à "detalhado e prolixo". Mas isso é de cada um, me sugere alguma edição rápida?

Comment: 2 parágrafos com 2 listas. O mesmo conteúdo com outra forma.

Comment: Espero que ajude, Edney. :)

Comment: Obrigado!
Achei que fosse uma sugestão do tipo: "tornar a leitura mais prosaica".
Eu realmente não entendo muito desse markdown usado nos foruns do stackexchange.

Comment: Não tem problema nenhum que não percebas. :) Se alguma vez precisares de ajuda, diz isso num comentário - mais cedo ou mais tarde passa alguém que te dá uma mãozinha com seja o que for que precises - formatações etc.

Answer (score 0):

"África Mãe África".
"The old man the boat".

Havia um famoso intelectual que só falava assim:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lWkl03RKpeM

Comment: Não vejo como isto responde. "África Mãe África" é suposto ser uma frase gramaticalmente correta e completa? Como?

Comment: @ANeves, dentro do humorismo em Portugal isto é considerado uma "referência". Passados 25 anos ainda é citado em conversa, motiva boa disposição. É parte da cultura contemporânea por cá. Qual a ligação? É o único personagem -que conheço- cuja marca era falar com uma estrutura de frase semelhante à do exemplo.

Comment: Então, "África Mãe África" é suposto ser uma frase completa e gramatical? É suposto ser um exemplo de "Teoria do Garden Path"? De que maneira é que é um exemplo melhor que "lar doce lar"? (Que não acho ser um exemplo desta teoria.) Continuo a não ser da opinião de que esta resposta responda à pergunta.